# Conditional property on a discrete random variable

Tags: statistics

So with a discrete random variable with a PMF

[image]

$P(X \leq 5) = P(1) + P(3) + P(5) = \frac{3}{4}$

$P(X \geq 2) = P(X \geq 3) = P(3) + P(5) + P(7) = \frac{3}{4}$

$P(X \leq 5 | X \geq 2) = \frac{P(X \leq 5 \cap X \geq 2)}{P(X \geq 2)} = \frac{(3/4)(3/4)}{3/4} = \frac{3}{4}$

Is this right? Does this mean they are independent?

Comment: $P(X\leq5 \cap X\geq2)=P(2 \leq X \leq 5)=P(3)+P(5).$

Comment: Ah I wasn't sure if I should multiple or just add them. Thanks.